# If any two items in a list is equal to a given number

Tags: python, beginner, k-sum

I just subscribed to the daily coding problems and received my first today.

The problem is:

> Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k. For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

This is what I came up with:

```
def anyequalto(x, y):
    for i in x:
        if y - i in x:
            return True


anyequalto([10, 15, 3, 7], 17)
```

I was wondering if anyone had any notes or alternatives as I'm very new to Python and programming.

Comment: Your revised code is actually less efficient. There is no point in creating a new list each time.

Comment: This puzzle must be making the rounds, because someone posted it on this site a few days ago: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208138/find-every-possible-pair-of-numbers-that-sum-up-to-n-number/208184#208184

Comment: Please do not add new code to your question. Your new code has a few aspects that deserve to be reviewed. You can do so in a different follow-up question. Please refer to the rules for that.

Comment: Your revised code doesn't work correctly with duplicate values. contains_pair_totalling([5, 5], 10) returns false. Sets don't contain duplicates, so your remove call breaks this case.

Comment: The original code didn’t work with the sum double any list value, either.  `anyequalto([5], 10)` returns `True`!

Answer (score 8):

There's a failing case you might have missed.  If the target number is *exactly twice the value of one of the entries*, then you'll wrongly return true.

Test case:

```
anyequalto([5], 10)
```

Besides that, try to think of a better name for the function.  Perhaps `contains_pair_totalling()` as a start?

Comment: Didn't think of that. I'd fix this by taking the number it's checking out of the list, then checking it and adding it back for the next run. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that would be a correct fix.  It might not be efficient for very large inputs; I don't know whether that's a concern.

Comment: @SimonJ you wouldn't need to add it back - if it is part of a pair summing to `k` then there won't be a next run, and if it isn't then it won't affect future runs.

Answer (score 6):

**Return value**

Adding a few tests, we have:

```
print(anyequalto([10, 15, 3, 7], 17))
print(anyequalto([10, 15, 3, 7], 18))
print(anyequalto([10, 15, 3, 7], 19))
```

giving

```
True
True
None
```

The `None` value seems a bit unexpected to me. We'd probably want `False` to be returned in that particular case.

Also, even if you expect `None` to be returned in that case, the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends being explicit for that (emphasis is mine):

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a
>   function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any
>   return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no
>   value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and **an
>   explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function
>   (if reachable)**.

**Names, documentation and tests**

The variables names could be clearer.

Also, the function behavior can be described in a docstring.

Finally, it could be worth writing tests for it.

You'd get something like:

```
def anyequalto(num_lst, n):
    """Return True if 2 numbers from `num_lst` add up to n, False otherwise."""
    for i in num_lst:
        if n - i in num_lst:
            return True
    return False

TESTS = [
    # Random tests cases
    ([10, 15, 3, 7], 17, True),
    ([10, 15, 3, 7], 18, True),
    ([10, 15, 3, 7], 19, False),
    # Edge case
    ([], 0, False),
    ([], 1, False),
    # Same value
    ([5, 5], 10, True),
    ([5], 10, True),
    # Zero
    ([5, 0], 0, True),
    ([5, 0], 5, True),
    ([5, 0], 2, False),
]

for (lst, n, expected_res) in TESTS:
    res = anyequalto(lst, n)
    if res != expected_res:
        print("Error with ", lst, n, "got", res, "expected", expected_res)
```

**Data structure**

At the moment, you can iterate on the list (via the `in` check) for each element of the list. This leads to an `O(n²)` behavior.

You can makes t hings more efficient by building a set to perform the `in` test in constant time and have an overall `O(n)` behavior.

```
def anyequalto(num_lst, n):
    """Return True if 2 numbers from `num_lst` add up to n, False otherwise."""
    num_set = set(num_lst)
    for i in num_set:
        if n - i in num_set:
            return True
    return False
```

**Using the Python toolbox**

The solution you are using could be written in a more concise and efficient way using the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) builtin.

You have something like:

```
def anyequalto(num_lst, n):
    """Return True if 2 numbers from `num_lst` add up to n, False otherwise."""
    num_set = set(num_lst)
    return any(n - i in num_set for i in num_set)
```

Comment: The any builtin is something I hadn't seen yet. Since someone pointed out that if the value of n is the exact double of an item in num_lst. How would that work out with any? If possible.

Comment: `anyequalto([5], 10)` should be `False`, so you cannot simply create `num_set` like this. You need to iterate over the numbers, check if `n-i` is in the set and only then add `i` to the set.

Comment: And `[5, 0], 0` should be `False`.

Comment: I relied on the original code behavior and made sure I didn't change it while making it more explicit via the corresponding test cases. Maybe I should have hilighted it as a bug (I do not quite remember how the problem was expressed initially).

Comment: Also, if I were to re-implement it based on that new behavior, I'd probably just use a Counter...

Comment: `Counter` would be interesting. Please do so!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix to the edge case. We want to check explicitly that we have a valid solution, which means that we want something akin to `any2` instead of `any` (since if we have just a single match then we have the problem case).

```
def anyequalto(numbers, k):
    number_set = set(numbers)
    solutions = [num for num in numbers
                 if k - num in number_set]
    return len(solutions) > 1
```

This fixes the edge case and still retains `O(n)` runtime since it uses a `set`.

```
>>> anyequalto([5], 10)
False
```

#### Aside

Right now this produces a list with the list comprehension used to generate `solutions` which one might argue is needlessly inefficient. I couldn't think of a stylistically good way to assert that a generator has more than one element aside from checking for `StopIteration` which I think is kinda clunky.

Comment: `next(iterator, sentinel)` will return `sentinel` if the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: Nice, it also works with `anyequalto([5, 5], 10) # True`.

Answer (score 2):

- As others have mentioned, your code could be more efficient with set lookup.
- It should return `False` with `[5]` and `10` as input parameters.
- Python method names are written in `snake_case`.
- Python is a dynamic language, which means method names and parameter names are very important. They make it easier to read your code and understand it again 6 months after having written it. `x` sounds like an unknown object or a float, not like a list of integers.

Here's a possible way to write the method:

```
def contains_pair_with_given_sum(numbers, desired_sum):
    unique_numbers = set()
    for number in numbers:
        if (desired_sum - number) in unique_numbers:
            return True
        unique_numbers.add(number)
    return False
```

It outputs:

```
contains_pair_with_given_sum([5, 10, 7], 12)
# True
contains_pair_with_given_sum([5], 10)
# False
```

You could also use the fact that a pair of integers is truthy in Python and return the pair when found:

```
def find_pair_with_given_sum(numbers, desired_sum):
    unique_numbers = set()
    for number in numbers:
        if (desired_sum - number) in unique_numbers:
            return (number, desired_sum - number)
        unique_numbers.add(number)
```

It outputs:

```
find_pair_with_given_sum([5, 10, 7], 12)
# (7, 5)
find_pair_with_given_sum([5], 10)
# None
```

Answer (score 1):

1. for a much faster way to check if a number is in some container, use a `set()`:
   `anyequalto({10, 15, 3, 7}, 17)`. even if you have to convert from a list first,
   it will still be faster to do that once rather than linearly search the list each
   iteration. This will make your function O(n) rather than O(n^2)
2. choose more expressive variable names that `x` and `y`. something like
   `numbers` and `k`
   j
3. If you want to write this in a more functional style, you could do:

   ```
   def anyequalto(numbers, k):
       numbers = set(numbers)
       return any((k-num) in numbers
                  for num in numbers)
   ```

   Because any will terminate early if the generator produces a true
   value, this will be very similar in speed to an iterative solution.

Comment: It should be `any(k in numbers for num in numbers)`, not `any(for num in numbers k in numbers)`.

Comment: `anyequalto([5], 10)` should be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would use `any` and `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

def anytwoequalto(numbers, k):
    return any(((i + j) == k) for i, j in combinations(numbers, 2))
```

`itertools.combinations` iterates over the given object returning tuples with the given number of items in them with no repetitions. eg.

```
combinations('ABCD', 2) =>
    (('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'))
```

`any` returns `True` if any of the expressions `((i + j) == k)` evaluate to `True`

If you wish to consider that an item can be added to itself, use `combinations_with_replacement` instead.

Note: depending on the version of Python you are using, you may need to add extra parentheses (`()`) around the expression inside the `any` call.

Hope this makes sense.